# Add Help Menu entry in QGIS 3 from `startup.py`

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, gui

I would like to add a menu entry in the Help menu pointing to some web ressource, say https://gis.stackexchange.com. The following code executed from the python console works perfect:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
import webbrowser

def open_gis_se():
    webbrowser.open('https://gis.stackexchange.com')

iface.helpMenu().addSeparator()

gis_se_action = QAction('Go to gis.stackexchange')
iface.helpMenu().addAction(gis_se_action)
gis_se_action.triggered.connect(open_gis_se)
```

Result when typed in the python console:

[image]

... but putting it into my `startup.py` has no effect (Help menu remains 'as it is').

In QGIS 2, the above code put in the `startup.py` adds the desired menu entry as expected.

Why?

Comment: Where did you place the _startup.py_ file? It should be placed in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3` as described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318222/qgis-3-startup-script-is-not-executed). Your code should have produced an error about `QAction` not being defined which can be rectified by adding `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction`.

Comment: Ooops!I had not seen your comment @joseph,sorry

Comment: @FranRaga - Don't be! I had a feeling the problem OP had was similar to mine so glad you answered this one too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great idea

you need place startup.py in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3`
and add missing import ,and voilá

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction
import webbrowser

def open_gis_se():
    webbrowser.open('https://gis.stackexchange.com')

iface.helpMenu().addSeparator()

gis_se_action = QAction('Go to gis.stackexchange')
iface.helpMenu().addAction(gis_se_action)
gis_se_action.triggered.connect(open_gis_se)
```

[image]