# QGIS 3.6 startup.py not executed

Tags: qgis

With QGIS 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 I can't get the `startup.py` file to execute. Checked the docs and default folders with `QStandardPaths.standardLocations(QStandardPaths.AppDataLocation)` and added the startup into the final folder `/home/jaume/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python` nothing happens. 
The test code I want to execute is:

```py
f = open("/home/jaume/aaa.txt","w+")
f.write("This is a line")
f.close()
```

I've tryed other silly code, added execution permissions, tested that this code runs in the python3 console, etc. Nothing happens. Any advice?

Comment: the correct folder is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3`, check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318817/49538 in your case I think is `/home/jaume/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3`

Comment: Thank you @FranRaga this works. Docs say something different: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file Wich is best, tell the devs to corrrect the search folder or tell the docs are incorrect....

Comment: I put my comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The correct folder is:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3`, check [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318817/49538) in your case I think is

```
/home/jaume/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3
```